# Do all hauptmoduln have integral coefficients in their Fourier expansion

Tags: modular-forms

Define Klein's modular $j$-invariant as  $$j(\tau) =  1728 \frac{g_2^3}{\Delta},$$ where $$ g_2 = 60 \sum_{(m,n)}' \Big( \frac{1}{m + n \tau} \Big)^4$$ and $$ g_3 = 60 \sum_{(m,n)}' \Big( \frac{1}{m + n \tau} \Big)^6$$ and $$\Delta = g_2^3 - 27 g_3^2.$$

It is well known (see e.g. Apostol *Modular Forms*, Theorem 1.20) that the Fourier expansion of $j(\tau)$ has integral coefficients, starting with $$j(\tau) = q^{-1} + 744 + 196883 q + ...$$

It is also well known that $j(\tau)$ is the principal modulus or *hauptmodul* for $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, meaning that it is the unique generator for the field of functions on $X(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ and serves as the isomorphism between $X(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}))$ and the Riemann sphere. Every other genus zero subgroup in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ has a principal modulus.

My question (finally) is: **Do the Fourier expansions of hauptmoduln all have integral coefficients?** I have looked up a couple (namely the hauptmoduln for $\Gamma_0(2)$ and $\Gamma_0(3)$ and this appears to be the case, but I am not sure how to look this up more generally.

Moreover, if the answer to my first question is yes, I want to ask: **Is there a conceptual reasons for why the fourier expansions of hauptmoduln are integral?** I ask the second question in particular because Apostol does not even introduce the notion of a hauptmodul, and his proof that the Fourier expansion of $j(\tau)$ has integral coefficients comes by manipulating the Eisenstein series given above.

Comment: For $\Gamma(n)$ I'm not sure but if $h(z) \in M_0(\Gamma_1(n))$ has rational coefficients at $i\infty$ then $h(z) \Delta(z)^2\in S_{24}(\Gamma_1(n))$, there we have a basis of forms with integers coefficients so $h(z) \Delta(z)^2 =\frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^J a_j f_j(z)$ for some integers $a_j,m$ and $m h(z) = \sum_{j=1}^J a_j f_j(z) \Delta(z)^{-2} $ has integers coefficients. Thus it suffices to show your Hauptmodul $h(z)$ has rational coefficients to obtain $m h(z) $ is an Hauptmodul with integer coefficients.

Comment: I think it is a conjecture that all modular forms of congruence subgroups have Fourier coefficients that are rational numbers with bounded denominators.